# mysql 5.5 failing to start [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'

Tags: mysql

Mysql has been working fine until now. Maybe upgrades and broken it. Running 5.5.43 on 12.04LTS. At first there was the error:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp'
```

in the `error.log`.

So I commented this option out in the `my.cnf` file and now it still will not start and there are no further error messages. How do I turn on more verbose messaging to see the error?

Comment: Reading through others questions I thought I had spotted the same problem. That is when you run sudo mysqld you see the error message Can't read from message file... The resolution provided was to reinstall mysql-server-core-5.5. I tried this and I still am getting the same error at start.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I ran sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server and this upgraded from 5.5 to 5.6. Oh well. But at least I have a running mysqld.